# Using geomnet in R on maps

Tags: r, networking, plot, coordinates, gis

I need to make a network on a map, with proper geographical references.

I've tried to make something like this: 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggCompNet/vignettes/examples-from-paper.html

(look the map at the bottom)
This is the head of tripnet:

```
    from_id    to_id q_trx      long       lat
9  20020101        0   241 -58.41441 -34.60768
10 20020102 20040108   537 -58.41950 -34.60722
11 20020102        0   561 -58.41950 -34.60722
12 20020103 20040108   543 -58.42359 -34.60714
13 20020103        0   551 -58.42359 -34.60714
14 20020104 20040108   490 -58.42688 -34.60397
```

Here's my code:

```
map <- get_map(location = c("long" = -58.416212, "lat" = -34.631330), zoom = 12)


ggmap(map) + geom_net(
  data = tripnet,
  labelon = TRUE,
  selfloops = TRUE,
  vjust = -0.5,
  ealpha = 0.5,
  aes(
    from_id = from_id,
    to_id = to_id,
    x = long ,
    y =  lat,
    linewidth = q_trx,
    colour = 'grey'
  )
) +
  scale_colour_manual("CABA", values = c("grey40")) +  theme_net() %+replace% theme(aspect.ratio =
                                                                                              NULL, legend.position = "bottom") +  coord_map()
```

Apparently there is no error but it just plots a map without the network.

Answer (score 1):

I've just noticed that every node needs to have its coordinates. Previously, I had deleted all rows with NA values in q_trx. Including them solved the problem.